# Print, cat, paste in R separated by newline character

Tags: r, output-formatting

I want to do the print the elements of a vector line by line in R like below

`1`

`2`

`3`

However, when I do `paste(c(1,2,3), "\n")` or `paste(c(1,2,3),sep = "\n")`, the new line never gets printed out. The same thing goes for `cat` as well. I always get the following:

`"1" "2" "3"`

I would like to know to get around this problem.

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
cat(paste(1:3), sep="\n")
1
2
3
```

Comment: `paste` is not necessary here, is it?

Answer (score 5):

`writeLines` is designed for this purpose. You need to supply a character vector though:

```
writeLines(as.character(1:3))
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 3):

The followings work in RStudio:

```
cat(1,2,3,sep="\n")
```

and

```
cat(1:3,sep="\n")
```

Both outputs are

```
1
2
3
```